# Changing raster display in QGIS to look same as ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: qgis, imagery, satellite, rgb

I have a strange problem. I have noticed that the same satelite imagery looks totally different in QGIS and ArcGIS.

The problem is that I need to get the same style in QGIS. I've tried to calculate statistics for every band in ArcGIS and applied this values to a display properities in QGIS but it doesn't work.

Manipulating standard deviation values in QGIS helps a liitle bit but the whole image is still more blue than it should be.

Can anyone give me some clue what can I do to improve this image style in qgis?

[image: Tiff_ArcGIS]

[image: Tiff_QGIS]

Comment: Have you tried some different settings for the raster's Style - Contrast Enhancement drop down?  The second image looks stretched.  QGIS doesn't have as many options as ArcGIS but you can try what they have and then try some other settings.